# Python giving me trouble converting list to chart output

Tags: python, list, charts, output

I have designed this code below which basically takes as an input, the number of rows, columns,highest value and lowest value from the user.

```
import random
import math


nrows=int(input("enter the number of rows: "))
ncols=int(input("enter the number of columns: "))
lowval=float(input("enter the lowest value: "))
highval=float(input("enter the highest value: "))

def list(nrows, ncols, lowval, highval):
    values=[[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0]]

    for r in range(nrows):
        for c in range(ncols):
            values[r][c] = random.uniform(lowval,highval+1)

    print(values)


list(nrows, ncols, lowval, highval)
```

Now the area which I'm struggling with is attempting to take the list and convert it into something more organized akin to a chart so that the output basically mirrors this for example:

```
Number of rows: 4
Number of columns: 3
Low value: -100
High value: 100

             0         1         2
   0     7.715     6.522    23.359
   1    79.955    -4.858   -71.112
   2    49.249   -17.001    22.338
   3    98.593   -28.473   -92.926
```

Any suggestions/ideas as to how I can have my output look like the one desired above?

EDIT: I understand there is a way to do this by using pandas but I Was more interested in figuring out to do it manually..

I have this code below that is somewhat close to the output that I wanted:

```
for i in range(ncols):
    for a in range(nrows):
        print('%-12i%-12i' % (random.uniform(lowval,highval+1), random.uniform(lowval,highval+1)))
```

this basically gives me an output of:

```
   enter the number of rows: 2
enter the number of columns: 3
enter the lowest value: 10
enter the highest value: 100
94          36          
95          33          
20          79          
17          19          
57          63          
60          30
```

What I need to do now is basically have my rows and coloumns match the input by the user, let me know if there is a way!

Answer (score 0):

You would use `pandas`.  It creates structured data exactly like that.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> low = -100.
>>> high = 100.
>>> nrows = 4
>>> ncols = 3
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(lowval, highval+1, (nrows, ncols)))
>>> print(df)
       0          1          2
0   7.247811  17.570162  32.860419
1   5.925314  14.012429  13.899928
2  22.602344  31.671225  18.199785
3  35.192664  11.216082  33.590036
```

Also, never call a function "`list`", since it will overwrite the default list constructor.

Comment: I'll check that out- I was looking to see if there was a way by manipulating code to have the output look like a basic chart(perhaps through loops,etc)

Comment: You could, in theory, but if there is something that does it for you, that seems more efficient.

Comment: Ah, I have attempted to do it manually with my edit, let me know if you guys can see where my errors are so far

Comment: very close now just need to somehow have the correct number of rows and coloums of user input and I'm golden